# how to use python3 shortcuts on emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, python3

I am new to emacs and I am trying to set python3 as default interpreter. 
I have installed from software centre the python plugin for emacs.

I can run a python3 file going to `pyexec-->execute file...-> python3 file`
and in a similar way I can run a region of code `pyexec-->execute region-> execute region python3`

I would like to execute python3 file and region using keyboard short cut

In particular i need something to run all the file and something to run the lightened region of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `py-shell-name` to `python3`, for example by using

<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>Return</kbd>`py-shell-name`

Comment: thanks for answer but I am very new to emacs. Can you explain a little better?  What is the value of customize-variable and after return should I write python3 or py-shell-name?

Comment: Press Meta-x, then Emacs will ask you for a command to run. Type `customize-variable`. Now Emacs will ask you for a variable to customize. Type `py-shell-name`. Emacs will open a `Custom` buffer where you can change the value for `Py Shell Name`. Change it to `python3` and klick the `Apply and Save` button.

Comment: when I type py-shell-name I receive a no match message and nothing else

Comment: ok it is partially working I have been able to follow your instruction after that I opened a python file. The problem is that now the command C-c l that was previously used to run a region of code in python 2.7 do not work anymore. I would like to use the command C-c l to run a region of code in python3 shell

Comment: By default "Execute Region" is bound to `C-c |` (pipe key) not `C-c l` (lower case L). Customizing `py-shell-name` shouldn't change the keyboard bindings.

Comment: o yes you are right! it's working. Thanks a lot