# How to use python3 in emacs on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, emacs, python3

I am using emacs in python mode.

To run a python file I use the command `C-c C-c`.

Emacs automatically start to run python 2.7 while I would like to use python3.

Once I have been able to solve using this method [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444566/how-to-use-python3-shortcuts-on-emacs) but now it is not working on ubuntu 14.04

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution which re-defines `python-shell-parse-command`:

```lisp
(require 'python)
(defun python-shell-parse-command ()
  "Return the string used to execute the inferior Python process."
  "/usr/bin/python3 -i"
  )
```

Calling `run-python` invokes `/usr/bin/python3 -i`.

---

*As a side note*

There are two modes for python: `python.el` (default) and [`python-mode.el`](https://launchpad.net/python-mode/). You cite binding from `python.el` so I gave a solution for `python.el`. I just wanted to mention that `python-mode.el` has a built-in command for the task: `python3`.

Comment: I am not totally sure that I am using python.el hoe can n i checkthis?

Comment: This works partially. Now when I use C-c C-c it runs the script on  python3.   The command C-c | used to evaluate only the lightened region does not work anymore

Answer (score 3):

Setting `(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")` in `.emacs` should be enough